Separate 3 translations to individual files in Notepad++ using Regular Expression
I have a document with following format:
In Line 1 there is English language text.
In Line 2 there is translation of English language in French.
In Line 3 there is translation of English language in German.
Again, in Line 4 there is English language text and then in the following lines its translation in French and German.
Each translation is separated by a newline character except the last line of the document where it ends in German translation without any newline.
I want to write a regex code to separate each language and save it to separate files using Notepad++
Here is the code which I have written:
Find : ^(.+\r)(.+\r)(.+\r)
How do I separate them and optimize the code as the document is approx more than 700 pages.

This is not a job for Notepad++. you'd better to write a script in your favorite scripting language.

I have my doubts you can do this in notepad++, IMHO you cant redirect to other file the result of regex. But you can use sample program in powershell like this:
foreach($line in Get-Content .\input.txt) {
    
    if($content.IndexOf($line)%3 -eq 0){
        Add-Content english.txt $line
    }
    if($content.IndexOf($line)%3 -eq 1){
        Add-Content french.txt $line 
    }
    if($content.IndexOf($line)%3 -eq 2){
        Add-Content german.txt $line 
    }
}

The idea is to check if the reminder (not 100% sure about the word) of the number of current line  is 0 which will mean this is english, 1 for french, 2 for german. And append the line to appropriate file
If you insist to to it in notepad++ you can use in "Replace" regex:
^(.+\r\n)(.+\r\n)(.+\r\n)

and replace it with
$1

for the english, save the file, then undo,
point the cursor on the begin of first line (again) and use
$2

for french, $3 for german
It is important to have newline character on the last line, otherwise will not work properly!

Thanks. I am not aware of powershell scripting. I believe there is an option to mark the match in Notepad++. I may have to run query 3 times, however, I am not able to find out the correct regex code to do that. I will keep this poweshell code though and give it a try.

@Shahid, added in answer one ugly solution for notepad++, please check it
